# How to have dynamic Jittered Back-off for wait and retry in .Net core using polly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, polly, retry-logic

I am implementing wait and [retry using jitter](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry#new-jitter-recommendation) see below. In the example below the delay
is same.

How can I make delay dynamic?

```
var delay = Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 3);
var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<FooException>().WaitAndRetryAsync(delay);
```

In my Project, I have Azure function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        builder.Services.RegisterService(configuration);
    }
}
```

```
public static IHttpClientBuilder RegisterService(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,IConfiguration configuration)
{
    return serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IService, Service()
               .AddPolicyHandler(RetryPolicyHandler.GetRetryPolicy())
}

public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var delay =Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 3);
    return HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().WaitAndRetryAsync(delay);
}
```

Comment: @itasutralia Currently you have 4 open polly related questions. Please consider to close the other three if you have received answers which are suitable for your needs.

Comment: @PeterCsala I have closed others polly questions. Thanks for help

Comment: Thank you. Does my post answer this question?

Comment: I have updated the code above. Question: If you see the update code. Startup class override configure method that call register service->RetryPolicy Startup-> Configure-> Register Service -> RetryPolicy My understanding is RetryPolicy will be called once (function startup) that will set the delay duration. Correct me if I am wrong? Sorry I am new to polly and github wiki does not have this information. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: I'm currently reading this on phone. Later today when I will sit at my computer I will reflect to the update.

Comment: Thanks PeterCsala. You are amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the delays are **not** the same.

The `DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2` will return an `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>` so, please issue this command:

```
var sleepDurations = delay.ToArray();
```

and use a debug visualizer to see they are different. If you run this experiment several times the delays will be always different.

[image: first run] [image: second run]

---

**UPDATE #1**

> My understanding is RetryPolicy will be called once (function startup) that will set the delay duration. Correct me if I am wrong

That's a wrong assumption. A new retry policy will be created for every `HttpClient` call. In order to demonstrate that let's have these two subsequent method calls:

```
await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us/408");
await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us/408");
```

and add some logging inside the `onRetry` delegate

```
.WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 3),
    onRetry: (dr, ts) => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Delay: {ts}"); //Replace this with ILogger                     
    })
```

then you will see something similar inside your logs:

```
Delay: 00:00:00.4752054
...
Delay: 00:00:01.2825508
...
Delay: 00:00:03.1409815
...
...
Delay: 00:00:01.2526426
...
Delay: 00:00:01.2919173
...
Delay: 00:00:00.3157069
```

As you can see not the same sequence of sleep durations are used for both `GetAsync` calls.

Comment: Hi @Peter, Thank you for response. I have updated the code above. 

Question: If you see the update code. Startup class override configure method that call register service->RetryPolicy

Startup-> Configure-> Register Service -> RetryPolicy

My understanding is RetryPolicy will be called once (function startup) that will set the delay duration. Correct me if I am wrong?

Sorry I am new to polly and github wiki does not have this information. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: @itaustralia I've updated my post, please check it!

Comment: thanks a lot. let me try. Again Thanks